# Environment Object Method error in Scene Delegate

Tags: mvvm, swiftui, environment-variables, environment, uiscenedelegate

SO Community

I have been self-teaching myself SwiftUI and I've just come across a problem while creating an application in the Scene Delegate. When I add an environment object method to the scene delegate to assign an object to the environment of a view hierarchy, Xcode sends these errors on my let contentView = ContentView().environmentObject(delegate.myData) line of code, "Expected member name following '.' ", and "Missing argument for parameter 'appData' in call ".

I will also attach a picture of my ContentView.swift File to show where I placed my @EnviromentObject reference within the body Content View. If you guys have any questions can you please try to help me out, this has been a bum time. Thanks.

Link to Scene Delegate.Swift file : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YV08h.png)
Link to ContentView.Swift file : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9n3T.png)

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

```
var window: UIWindow?


func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options 
     connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    
    let app = UIApplication.shared
    let delegate = app.delegate as! AppDelegate
    
     let contentView = ContentView()
             .environmentObject(delegate.myData)

 
    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`EnvironmentObject`s are not passed via parameter like you're trying to do in your `ContentView` initializer. Instead, they are passed "magically" behind-the-scenes and exposed via the `@EnvironomentObject` property wrapper.

My suggestion is to get rid of your `init` method and use `onAppear { }` to set your `contentData` fields:

```
var body: some View {
  VStack {
    //...
  }.onAppear {
    // do initial setup
  }
}
```

You should also make sure that you're using the same capitalization of `appData` -- you're using `appdata` sometimes, which is leading to many of your compilation errors.